# Wait for jar run from batch to finish?

Tags: java, batch-file

I start a jar file by batch and want to wait for that tool to finish before I continue with the next batch command. How could I do this?

```
java -jar "tool.jar" parameter /wait
```

Would this wait for the tool to end? Or would the jar be executed asynchronously?

Comment: I have tried this by I'm not really sure. That's why I ask the community.

Comment: The `java`-command will stop blocking until your `main()`-method returns. It should therefor "wait" by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
call java -jar "tool.jar" parameter /wait
```

If you run a program or another bat file with call, the calling bat file will wait, until the called bat file finished.